# Filter array in array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, filter, functional-programming, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects. Each object in array has also an array. I would like to filter both of arrays, parent one and nested one. For example I have an array like:

```
[{list:[1,2]},{list:[1,2,3]},{list:[1,2,3,4]}]
```

When I apply filter, which returns objects in which has list elements which has value greater than 2 and also nested list itself is filtered. It should return

```
[{list:[3]},{list:[3,4]}]
```

Obj1 is not returned, because list inside it does not have any values which are greater 2, for Obj2 only list:[3] is returned and for Obj3 only list:[3,4] is returned

Is it possible to achieve without mutating original list?

The following code filters objects which has elements which are greater than 2

```
parent
  .filter(obj => obj.list.some(el => el > 2))
```

What should I do next?
If I apply a filter for nested array like

```
...
  .filter(obj => obj.list.filter(el => el > 2))
```

Then as a result I get `[[3],[3,4]]` but not object itself. Maybe anyone knows solution for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I'd filter the sublist and then check its length:

```js
var parent = [{list:[1,2]},{list:[1,2,3]},{list:[1,2,3,4]}];

parent = parent
  .filter(obj => {
    obj.list = obj.list.filter(el => el > 2);
    return obj.list.length > 0; // Technically just `return obj.list.length;` would work; I prefer the clarity of the comparison
  });
console.log(parent);
```

And yes, the above could be done more concisely; I think the clarity suffers, but it's a judgement call:

```js
var parent = [{list:[1,2]},{list:[1,2,3]},{list:[1,2,3,4]}];

parent = parent.filter(obj => (obj.list = obj.list.filter(el => el > 2)).length);
console.log(parent);
```

Comment: Technically should we not use let instead of var?

Comment: @Thalaivar: *Technically?* No, both are perfectly valid in ES2015. :-) (I do tend to use `let` instead of `var` when I'm thinking ES2015, though; in the above it would be as much a matter of style as anything else.)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to TJ Crowder's answer, I'd like to mention that you still getting mutated original list items.

It would be better to map initial array into new items with filtered `list` property and then filter empty lists.

```js
const parent = [{list:[1,2]},{list:[1,2,3]},{list:[1,2,3,4]}];

const filtered = parent
    // filter nested lists first
    .map(obj => {
         // here we can use Object.assign to make shallow copy of obj, to preserve previous instance unchanged
         return Object.assign({}, obj, {
             list: obj.list.filter(el => el > 2)
         })
    })
    // then omit all items with empty list
    .filter(obj => obj.list.length > 0)
console.log(filtered);
```